# Spawn slots and view using Photon Unity Networking

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm developing multiplayer cards game in Unity and using in my scene I have a table object with 5 chairs objects for 5 players, and 1 camera.

Is it possible using PUN to spawn all players so that they can see the view from a single camera but sit in different chairs?

For example, I have scene like on photo.

If I'm first or second or fourth player who connected in room, I'm spawned on chair 1 and seeing another 4 players on chairs 2,3,4,5.

If another player's first or second or fourth players who connected in room, They must spawned on chair 1 and seeing me and 3 another players on chairs 2,3,4,5.

[image]

Comment: Yoir question is to vague .. the answer is: Yes. But if you wanted to know how to implement this you should rephrase your question and add some more details .. like e.g. some code of what you tried so far.

Comment: @derHugo thank u. I am only at the beginning of this journey.At this stage it is enough for me to get confirmation that it is possible. I will study it further. Can you tell me which way to go, which methods to look at?

Comment: @AxelVipovski you can do it nicely with Photon’s CustomProperties. When you join check available positions and take one. All players in the room and new players will automatically sync with this data.

Comment: @lggy but if position on chair 1 is busy by another player I can’t take it, it’s not my case.

Comment: @lggy For example, take any poker mobile game, when I’m join room, my position always on the bottom of my screen, if you join in this room your position also on the bottom of Your screen, but we see each other in the different position on the our screens, on the bottom always local player. I need some thing like this, but in 3d scene

Comment: @AxelVipovski obviously it is your case .. I'ld say what Iggy tried to say is e.g. have a list of the chairs and via photon synchronize whether a chair is taken or not. Then any new client will simply go through the list and take the first chair which is not taken yet. Where and how you place the camera depending on that is completely separated by this task.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for choosing Photon!

Yes, this is possible in Photon Unity Networking.
While I think it's not something related directly to Photon.

I think you can do this in, at least, two different ways:

1- Attach a disabled camera to each player prefab. When a player prefab is instantiated: check if it's local/mine. If it's the case, disable the main camera and enable the camera on the local player prefab just instantiated. the camera should point according to the GameObject's position/rotation.

2- When a player prefab is instantiated: check if it's local/mine. If it's the case, move the main camera to the view according to the position/rotation of the local player prefab just instantiated.

Of course, the spawn positions are known on all clients probably at compile time. And mapping a position to the player is done by position index and actor number.